# Find highest possible screen resolution from command line

Tags: command-line, powershell, resolution, batch-file, cmd.exe

With Powershell, I can request the current screen resolution. **this is not what I'm trying to do.** I'm trying to find the **maximum resolution** I can set the screen to (slider all up). Is this even possible from Powershell/Command line?

After I got the maximum resolution, I want to set the screen to this resolution. So I'm just looking for a way to set the screen to the highest resolution possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are hints for command line (and we can transform it to PowerShell): start with

```
wmic path Win32_VideoController
wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription
wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution
wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution
wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentNumberOfColors
wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentRefreshRate
```

Then we can obtain desired values parsing output(s) from

```
wmic path Win32_VideoSettings get Setting
```

Finally we could set desired properties with

`wmic path Win32_VideoController set ...`

Although - all the mentioned properties seem to be **read-only**, at least on my retired Win-XP...

Cf.  [WMIC - Take Command-line Control over WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)